# Deploying vsto on a server

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ms-word, vsto

I have a word vsto project. I signed the manifest with a test certificate, using the reate tewst certificate button in the Signing tab of the project propertie. After installing the vsto on the server, I used a custom made application that call the vsto and try to bind some data on it. However I have the Customized functionality in this application will not work because it has not been granted trust exception that shows in the event viwer and there is no data bound in my document.

I use VS2010 to create the projet and its for Word 2007.

Any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: btw, the certificate is trust on the server, so I think that the error message is not the one that should show up.